# Error when executing a mysql store procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a simple stored procedure that will drop a view. I am learning stored procedures in mysql so bear with me,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dropView (
    IN viewName varchar(4000)
)
BEGIN
    
    SET @sql:=CONCAT('DROP VIEW ',@viewName);
        PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @SQL;
        EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And i am calling the above like so,

```
SET @theView = '`Report`;';

CALL dropView(@theView);
```

I am getting the error message,

***Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1***

I am using **mysql 8.0.17**

According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) i can use 'CREATE/DROP VIEW' in a prepared mysql.

Comment: Change `@viewName` by `viewName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@viewNameis` a [9.4. User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and `viewName` one stored procedure parameter ([13.1.17 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-routines.html)), are different variables.